# How does Common Lisp's "loop for" macro work with multiple "and"ed counters?

Tags: common-lisp

The following Common Lisp code does not produce the output I would expect it to:

```
(loop for a from 5 to 10
      and b = a do
      (format t "~d ~d~%" a b))
```

Using SCBL, it produces this output:

```
5 5
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
10 9
```

I was expecting the values of a and b to be the same on each line.

I have searched the web for good documentation of the loop macro in this instance but couldn't find much.  I'd appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(loop for a from 5 to 10
      and b = a
      do (format t "~d ~d~%" a b))
```

Above code can be seen conceptually close to a PSETF . The values are updated in 'parallel'. The reason is the AND.

Let's replace AND with FOR:

```
(loop for a from 5 to 10
      for b = a
      do (format t "~d ~d~%" a b))
```

Above will update the variables conceptually close to a usual SETF, 'sequentially'.

```
CL-USER 20 > (loop for a from 5 to 10
                   for b = a
                   do (format t "~d ~d~%" a b))
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
```

For an explanation see the [Common Lisp HyperSpec 6.1.2.1 Iteration Control](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_aba.htm):

> If multiple iteration clauses are used
>   to control iteration, variable
>   initialization and stepping occur
>   sequentially by default. The *and*
>   construct can be used to connect two
>   or more iteration clauses when
>   sequential binding and stepping are
>   not necessary. The iteration behavior
>   of clauses joined by *and* is analogous
>   to the behavior of the macro *do* with
>   respect to *do**.

Answer (score 3):

Step forms of AND clauses are evaluated prior to any of the variables being given their new values. Use `for b = a then a` instead to force in-order evaluation.

Ref. http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html#equals-then-iteration

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I tried "for b = a then a" and it produced the same output, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried "a then a" on SBCL and LispWorks and it had the same results.  Oh well, thanks anyway!